# Webpack bundling module which I want to be loaded dynamically to entry point

Tags: javascript, webpack, module

Below code seems like using the [dynamic import](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports):

```js
(function executeApplication(): void {

  const loadDataButton: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById("LoadDataButton");
  if (loadDataButton !== null) {
    loadDataButton.addEventListener("click", (): void => {
      (async function handler(): Promise<void> {
        console.log("Checkpoint 1");
        const loadedValue: string = await loadDataOnDemand();
        console.log(loadedValue);
      })().catch((): void => { /* */ });
    });
  }
})();


async function loadDataOnDemand(): Promise<string> {

  console.log("Checkpoint 2");
  const MODULE: { default: string; DYNAMICALLY_LOADED_CONST_FROM_TS_MODULE: string; } =
      await import("./DynamicLoadingTesting/TypeScriptModuleForDynamicLoading");
  console.log("Checkpoint 3");
  console.log(MODULE);


  return MODULE.DYNAMICALLY_LOADED_CONST_FROM_TS_MODULE;
}
```

However actually `TypeScriptModuleForDynamicLoading.ts` has been bundled to entry point:

```
FrontendLogicPreProcessingTesting:
  asset FrontendLogicPreProcessingTesting.js 11.2 KiB [emitted] (name: FrontendLogicPreProcessingTesting)
  ./FrontendLogicPreProcessingTesting.ts 2.28 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./DynamicLoadingTesting/TypeScriptModuleForDynamicLoading.ts 419 bytes [built] [code generated]
  FrontendLogicPreProcessingTesting (webpack 5.4.0) compiled successfully in 710 ms
```

[image]

No webpack errros, and in output in browser seems to be correct:

[image]

My Webpack config:

```
{
  name: 'FrontendLogicPreProcessingTesting',
  context: 'D:\\IntelliJ IDEA\\XXXXX\\ProjectBuildingCommonTest\\00-Source\\FrontendLogicPreProcessingTesting'
,
  target: 'web',
  entry: {
    FrontendLogicPreProcessingTesting: 'D:/IntelliJ IDEA/XXXXX/ProjectBuildingCommonTest/00-Source/FrontendLogic
PreProcessingTesting/FrontendLogicPreProcessingTesting.ts'
  },
  output: {
    path: 'D:\\IntelliJ IDEA\\XXXXX\\ProjectBuildingCommonTest\\01-DevelopmentBuild\\FrontendLogicPreProcessin
gTesting',
    publicPath: './',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: 'loading_on_demand/partial__[id].js'
  },
  mode: 'development',
  watch: true,
  devtool: 'eval-cheap-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object]
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.mjs', '.js', '.ts' ],
    alias: { vue: 'vue/dist/vue.common.js' }
  },
  plugins: [
    DefinePlugin { definitions: [Object] },
    ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin { options: [Object] },
  ],
  optimization: { minimize: false, emitOnErrors: true }
}
```

I using webpack 5.x.x., but I faced with same problem when used 4.x.x.

My TypeScript config:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "es2017",
    "strict": true,

    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowJs": false,

    "experimentalDecorators": true,

    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {

    },

    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true
  }
}
```

Which conditions of dynamic loading has not been satisfied?

Comment: Waiting for an answer.

Comment: Can you check that when the `loadDataOnDemand` is called, there is indeed no extra request for a JS chunk in the browser devtools network tab?

Comment: @Jackyef, all console outputs on screenshot will not appear until click button. Therefore `loadDataOnDemand` called on click button.

Comment: I wasn't questioning whether `loadDataOnDemand` was called or not. I wanted to know if the browser send a request for a JS chunk when `loadDataOnDemand` is called. Could you confirm that?

Comment: @Jackyef, I don't see it in "Network" tab... Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgixl.png).

Comment: That was helpful, thanks! I noticed you are using `module: "CommonJS"` in tsconfig, which will cause tsc to change all dynamic import to require. Try changing it to `module: "esnext"`

Comment: @Jackyef, you are right! Please post the answer width explanations and I'll give you the reputation prize.

Comment: Done, glad it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently using `module: "CommonJS"` inside `tsconfig.json`, which will cause all dynamic `import()` to be transformed into `require()` calls before Webpack can actually see them. For Webpack to be able to generate new chunks, Webpack has to see dynamic `import()` calls.

Setting `module: "esnext"` will make it so the dynamic `import()` aren't transformed into `require()`, so Webpack can handle them properly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Your reward as I promised ^_~

Answer (score 0):

`webpackMode: lazy` [magic comment](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments) might help.

It should generate a separate chunk for `DynamicLoadingTesting/TypeScriptModuleForDynamicLoading.js`.

```
async function loadDataOnDemand(): Promise<string> {

  console.log("Checkpoint 2");
  const MODULE: { default: string; DYNAMICALLY_LOADED_CONST_FROM_TS_MODULE: string; } =
      await import(
       /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
       "./DynamicLoadingTesting/TypeScriptModuleForDynamicLoading"
);
  console.log("Checkpoint 3");
  console.log(MODULE);


  return MODULE.DYNAMICALLY_LOADED_CONST_FROM_TS_MODULE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry, but nothing changed ...