# How to pass separate TypeScript config for TSNode when it has being indecency running by Mocha & IntellIJ IDEA?

Tags: node.js, typescript, intellij-idea, mocha.js, ts-node

Although TS-Node [started the ECMAScript modules support](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1007), it has a lot of limitations and below example:

```js
import { assert as Assert } from "chai";


describe("firstTest", (): void => {

  it("", (): void => {
    Assert.isTrue(true);
  });

});
```

does not work with next settings:

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",

    "strict": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,

    "skipLibCheck": true,

    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {},

    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true
  }
}
```

**.mocharc.yaml**

```yaml
extension:
  - ts

spec: "**/*.test.ts"

require:
  - ts-node/register
  - tsconfig-paths/register
```

Error:

```
import { assert as Assert } from "chai";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I need the ECMAScript modules because the Webpack dynamic loading [does not work with CommonJS modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64890696/webpack-bundling-module-which-i-want-to-be-loaded-dynamically-to-entry-point). So the conceptual solution is create the additional `tsconfig.json` for TSNode or pass modules type via console. [It's has been documented](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#loading-tsconfigjson) how to do it for TSNode, but here I don't execute TSNode directly - I launch the Mocha via IntelliJ IDEA:

[image]

IntelliJ IDEA and, I suppose, all IDEs of this family including WebStorm generates the below command (added the line breaks):

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" 
"D:\XXX\MyProject\node_modules\mocha\bin\mocha" --require ts-node/register --ui bdd --reporter C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\203.7148.57\plugins\NodeJS\js\mocha-intellij\lib\mochaIntellijReporter.js 
"D:\XXX\MyProject\Test\Test.test.ts" --grep "^firstTest "
```

Now how to set `CommonJS` modules type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to **ts-node**'s documentation ([search for IntelliJ](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node)), you can create an alternative tsconfig.json (containing the option **"module": "CommonJS"**) and enforce it for Mocha tests using environment variable **TS_NODE_PROJECT**. In the **configuration** corresponding to your Mocha testing, in the **Environment variables** section, you set this variable to the pathname of this alternative tsconfig.json. Note, multiple tsconfig.json files can use one common "base" file and extend/partially override it ([see](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#extends)).